# JSF 2+Spring 3 integration-data not visible in page

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I am apparently new to Spring 3 and JSF 2. I am trying to develop a dummy application by integrating both the frameworks. When i access my page **.../MyNotes/home.xhtml** , no data is being displayed. 
I am using tomcat 7 server, and there is no error being printed in the log file
Here are my following files :

1. **POM.xml :**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.MyNotes</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyNotes</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MyNotes Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring 3 dependency -->
    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-330 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MyNotes</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

2. **web.xml :**

```html
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>

    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>

  </listener>

  <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

3. **applicationContext.xml :**

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <bean id="loginBO" class="com.test.login.boimpl.LoginBOImpl">
  </bean>
```

4. **faces-config.xml :**

```html
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
  <application>
    <el-resolver>
      org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
  </application>

  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.test.login.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>loginBO</property-name>
      <value>#{loginBO}</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
```

5. **loginBOImpl :**

```html
public class LoginBOImpl implements LoginBO{ public String createUser() { return "JSF 2 + Spring Integration"; }
```

6. **LoginBean :**

```html
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    LoginBO loginBO;

    //getters and setters
    public void setLoginBO(LoginBO loginBO) {
        this.loginBO = loginBO;
    }

    //add a new customer data into database
        public String addCustomer(){
            return loginBO.createUser();     

        }
```

7.**home.xhtml :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
  <title>Insert title here</title>

  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
  <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</h:head>
<h:body>
  <p>HI...!!!!</p>
  #{loginBean.addCustomer()}
</h:body>
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issue. I am running Tomcat 7, so EL comes packaged with it. What i did wrong was, in pom.xml i again had a dependency for el

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Removed this dependency, and everything was perfect.